# How to populate RecyclerView with AppWidgetHostViews?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am trying to populate RecyclerView with AppWidgetHostViews but I'm not really sure how to do that. I found a way in which they create a LinearLayout, cast it to ViewGroup and call viewList.add(hostView). I would like to create RecyclerView instead and this is the way I tried:

This is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<View
    android:id="@+id/appWidget"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

This is my adapter:

```
public class AppWidgetAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AppWidgetAdapter.AppWidgetHolder> {

private List<View> viewList = new ArrayList<>();

public void setData(List<View> list) {
    viewList.clear();
    viewList.addAll(list);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public AppWidgetHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.app_widget_layout, parent, false);
    return new AppWidgetHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AppWidgetHolder holder, int position) {
    View view = getItem(position);
    holder.setView(view);
}

private View getItem(int position) {
    return !viewList.isEmpty() ? viewList.get(position) : null;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return viewList.size();
}

class AppWidgetHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private View view;

    AppWidgetHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        view = (View) itemView.findViewById(R.id.app_widget);
    }

    private void setView (View view) {
        // ?
    }

}
```

}

And inside my fragment:

```
private List<View> viewList = new ArrayList<>();

mAdapter = new AppWidgetAdapter();
mRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
viewList.add((View) event.eventObject);
mAdapter.setData(viewList);
```

Event object is AppWidgetHostView.. I don't know how to cast it to bind it in onBindViewHolder() method... Is there a method in View object I can call to pass it AppWidgetHostView, like ViewGroup has add() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, maybe it's not the best way, but it works..

I replaced View with FrameLayout inside XML, and changed my ViewHolder:

```
  class AppWidgetHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private FrameLayout view;

    AppWidgetHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        view = (FrameLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.app_widget);
    }

    private void setView (View view) {
        if(view.getParent() != null) {
            ((ViewGroup)view.getParent()).removeView(view);
        }
        this.view.addView(view);
    }

}
```